# How to find out the file offset of an opened file?

Tags: linux, open-files

My problem is that with
`lsof -p pid` 
I can find out the list of opened file of a process whose process id is pid. But is there a way to find out the file offset of each accessed file ?

Please give me some suggestions ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

On linux, you can find the position of the file descriptor number `N` of process `PID` in `/proc/$PID/fdinfo/$N`. Example:

```
$ cat /proc/687705/fdinfo/36
pos:    26088
flags:  0100001
```

The same file can be opened several times with different positions using several file descriptors, so you'll have to choose the relevant one in the case there are more than one. Use:

```
$ readlink /proc/$PID/fd/$N
```

to know what is the file to which the corresponding file descriptor is attached (it might not be a file, in this case the symlink is dangling).

Comment: $ find  /proc/$PID/fd  -type l  -exec  stat --format="%N"  '{}'  ';'    as an alternative to  readlink

Answer (score 17):

`lsof` can do this, with the `-o` option.

Under Linux, it gets its information from `/proc`, so you can [get it there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34751/how-to-find-out-the-file-offset-of-an-opened-file/34754#34754) as well.

Comment: I can confirm this works as well. The offset is given as HEX, though.